# Optimizing squish() method further

Tags: java, linked-list

Part II of this [question](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61bf06/hw/hw3/readme.pdf) says:

> Fill in the `squish()` method in the `SList` class so that it performs as indicated in the comment. Your solution should not use arrays, nor should it use your `smoosh()` method. Do not change the prototype of the `SList` constructor or the `insertEnd` method; our test software will call them.

Below is the code written as a solution in `squish()` method. Modular testing is done for this method.

```
public class SList {

  private SListNode head;
  private int size;

  /**
   *  SList() constructs an empty list.
   **/

  public SList() {
    size = 0;
    head = null;
  }

  /**
   *  isEmpty() indicates whether the list is empty.
   *  @return true if the list is empty, false otherwise.
   **/

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size == 0;
  }

  /**
   *  length() returns the length of this list.
   *  @return the length of this list.
   **/

  public int length() {
    return size;
  }

  /**
   *  insertFront() inserts item "obj" at the beginning of this list.
   *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
   **/

  public void insertFront(Object obj) {
    head = new SListNode(obj, head);
    size++;
  }

  /**
   *  insertEnd() inserts item "obj" at the end of this list.
   *  @param obj the item to be inserted.
   **/

  public void insertEnd(Object obj) {
    if (head == null) {
      head = new SListNode(obj);
    } else {
      SListNode node = head;
      while (node.next != null) {
        node = node.next;
      }
      node.next = new SListNode(obj);
    }
    size++;
  }


  /**
   *  squish() takes this list and, wherever two or more consecutive items are
   *  equal(), it removes duplicate nodes so that only one consecutive copy
   *  remains.  Hence, no two consecutive items in this list are equal() upon
   *  completion of the procedure.
   *
   *  After squish() executes, the list may well be shorter than when squish()
   *  began.  No extra items are added to make up for those removed.
   *
   *  For example, if the input list is [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ], the
   *  output list is [ 0 1 0 3 1 0 ].
   *
   *  IMPORTANT:  Be sure you use the equals() method, and not the "=="
   *  operator, to compare items.
   **/

  public void squish() {
      // Fill in your solution here. (Ours is eleven lines long.)
      SListNode prevNode = null;
      SListNode curNode = null;
      int size = this.length();
      if(size >= 2){
          prevNode = this.head;
          curNode = this.head.next;  
      }
      if(!this.isEmpty()){
        while(size >= 2){
            if(prevNode.item.toString().equals(curNode.item.toString())){
                prevNode.next = curNode.next;
                size--;
                if(size >= 2){
                    curNode = curNode.next;
                }
            }else{
                size--;
                if(curNode.next != null){
                    prevNode = curNode;
                    curNode = curNode.next;

                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
  public String toString() {
    int i;
    Object obj;
    String result = "[  ";

    SListNode cur = head;

    while (cur != null) {
      obj = cur.item;
      result = result + obj.toString() + "  ";
      cur = cur.next;
    }
    result = result + "]";
    return result;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {
   String result;
   int i;
   System.out.println("\nLet's squish linked lists!\n");

    int[] test5 = {3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
    SList list5 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test5.length; i++) {
      list5.insertEnd(new Integer(test5[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list5.toString() + ":");
    list5.squish();
    result = list5.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  3  7  4  5  2  0  8  5  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    int[] test6 = {6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3};
    SList list6 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test6.length; i++) {
      list6.insertEnd(new Integer(test6[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list6.toString() + ":");
    list6.squish();
    result = list6.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  6  3  6  3  6  3  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    int[] test7 = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
    SList list7 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test7.length; i++) {
      list7.insertEnd(new Integer(test7[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list7.toString() + ":");
    list7.squish();
    result = list7.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  4  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    int[] test8 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    SList list8 = new SList();
    for (i = 0; i < test8.length; i++) {
      list8.insertEnd(new Integer(test8[i]));
    }
    System.out.println("squishing " + list8.toString() + ":");
    list8.squish();
    result = list8.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");

    SList list9 = new SList();
    System.out.println("squishing " + list9.toString() + ":");
    list9.squish();
    result = list9.toString();
    System.out.println(result);
    TestHelper.verify(result.equals("[  ]"),
                      "BAD SQUISH!!!  No biscuit.");
  }
}
```

**`SListNode`**

```
class SListNode {
  Object item;
  SListNode next;


  /**
   *  SListNode() (with two parameters) constructs a list node referencing the
   *  item "obj", whose next list node is to be "next".
   */

  SListNode(Object obj, SListNode next) {
    item = obj;
    this.next = next;
  }

  /**
   *  SListNode() (with one parameter) constructs a list node referencing the
   *  item "obj".
   */

  SListNode(Object obj) {
    this(obj, null);
  }
}
```

**`TestHelper`**

```
public class TestHelper {

  /**
   *  verify() checks an invariant and prints an error message if it fails.
   *  If invariant is true, this method does nothing.  If invariant is false,
   *  the message is printed, followed by a dump of the program call stack.
   *
   *  @param invariant  the condition to be verified
   *  @param message  the error message to be printed if the invariant fails to
   *                  hold true.
   **/

  static void verify(boolean invariant, String message) {
    if (!invariant) {
      System.out.println("*** ERROR:  " + message);
      Thread.dumpStack();
    }
  }
}
```

Test output:

> ```
> Let's squish linked lists!
>
> squishing [  3  7  7  7  4  5  5  2  0  8  8  8  8  5  ]:
> [  3  7  4  5  2  0  8  5  ]
> squishing [  6  6  6  6  6  3  6  3  6  3  3  3  3  3  3  ]:
> [  6  3  6  3  6  3  ]
> squishing [  4  4  4  4  4  ]:
> [  4  ]
> squishing [  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]:
> [  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  ]
> squishing [  ]:
> [  ]
> ```

Please comment on the readability aspect of the `squish()` method.

Can you please guide me on squeezing this code to 11 lines?

Note: This code is not intended to follow OOP principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much about line numbers. The way I take it, the task doesn't say that you have to stay below 11 lines, but just that their solution is 11 lines, so that you have a general idea how long a solution might be (so if your at e.g. 50 lines, you know you are off track).

**size**

Your local `size` variable is poorly named, as it doesn't represent the size of the list, but is just an iterator variable.

Also, the `size` field will contain the wrong value if `squish` removed a node.

**Early Return and simplified size check**

You can combine your size checks:

```
    if (size < 2) {
        return;
    }
```

And then you can assign `prevNode` and `curNode` like this:

```
    SListNode prevNode = this.head;
    SListNode curNode = this.head.next;
```

This is more readable and saves you lines.

**Null Values and toString**

The value of a node can be null right now as insert doesn't check for this. But your `squish` method cannot handle null values.

**equals and toString**

Remove the call to `toString`, it doesn't make that much sense, and might return false results, depending on the `equals` implementation.

**Checking if next node is null**

You are handling this inconsistently: The first time, you use `if (size >= 2)` to check if `curNode.next` will be null, the second time you use `if (curNode.next != null)`. You should use the same check in both cases.

Also you actually only need to check once: You can move it outside the if statement as it gets executed either way.

And I don't think that you even need that check. If size is smaller than 2, the while loop will stop anyways.

**Code**

If you follow all the advice, your code would look like this:

```
// NOTE: size field might be wrong after calling this method, and it doesn't work with null values in nodes
public void squish() {
    // Fill in your solution here. (Ours is eleven lines long.)
    if (size < 2) {
        return;
    }

    SListNode prevNode = this.head;
    SListNode curNode = this.head.next;
    while (size >= 2) {
        if (prevNode.item.equals(curNode.item)) {
            prevNode.next = curNode.next;
        } else {
            prevNode = curNode;
        }
        curNode = curNode.next;
        size--;
    }
}
```

Which is already a bit shorter. I wouldn't reduce the lines any further, it will just decrease readability.

But if you really want to, you could remove `curNode`, and thus also the check:

```
public void squish() {
    SListNode prevNode = this.head;
    while (size >= 2) {
        if (prevNode.item.equals(prevNode.next.item)) {
            prevNode.next = prevNode.next.next;
        } else {
            prevNode = prevNode.next;
        }
        size--;
    }
}
```

This would also give you two lines to spare, which is even enough to properly maintain the `size` field:

```
// maintains size field, but still doesn't handle null values in nodes
public void squish() {
    SListNode prevNode = this.head;
    for (int i = this.size; i >=2; i--) {
        if (prevNode.item.equals(prevNode.next.item)) {
            prevNode.next = prevNode.next.next;
            this.size--;
        } else {
            prevNode = prevNode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i just missed two declarations. copy-paste error.

Comment: @overexchange [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). I'll allow your editing this time since it is in code that was not the focus of the review. However, in general it would be unfair to edit away problems that have been pointed out in an answer.

Comment: @200_success Sure, will follow next time.

Answer (score 1):

In a singly linked list, it's **easier to inspect subsequent nodes** than to keep information about previous nodes.  It's hard enough having to worry about the possibility that `head` might be `null`; having to worry about two nodes possibly being `null` adds a lot of complication.

The `size` variable in `squish()` is misleadingly named: it actually counts the number of remaining nodes to be considered, not the size of the list.  Even worse, it **shadows the instance variable** named `size`.  As a result, lists become self-inconsistent and report the **wrong length** after being squished.  Actually, there is no reason why a `squish()` method should need to know about either the size of the list.  It should be able to operate myopically, operating based on what it sees in the neighbourhood of the current node.

Checking for `if(!this.isEmpty()) { … }` is **redundant** with `while(size >= 2) { … }`.  The innermost `if(size >= 2)` is also redundant with `while(size >= 2)`; it is safe to execute `curNode = curNode.next` unconditionally.  Similarly, `if(curNode.next != null)` looks like a superfluous check.  The harm in having these redundant conditions is not so much in having a few more lines of code.  Rather, more conditions means **fewer invariants or violated invariants**, making it hard to analyze the code.

You shouldn't compare node items by **comparing their string representations**.  Checking `prevNode.item.equals(curNode.item)` would be more appropriate.  (This assumes that nodes never contain a null `item`.)

### Suggested solution for `squish()`

```
public void squish() {
    for (SListNode cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next) {
        // Seek the next node with a different value
        SListNode seek;
        for (seek = cur.next; seek != null; seek = seek.next) {
            if ((cur.item == null) != (seek.item == null)) break;
            if (cur.item != null && !cur.item.equals(seek.item)) break;
            this.size--;
        }
        cur.next = seek;
    }
}
```

`if ((cur.item == null) != (seek.item == null)) break;` is done out of paranoia, in case a node can contain a `null` item.

### Testing

`insertEnd()` is a less efficient operation than `insertFront()`.  **Build your lists by manipulating the head.**

```
int[] test5 = {3, 7, 7, 7, 4, 5, 5, 2, 0, 8, 8, 8, 8, 5};
SList list5 = new SList();
for (i = test5.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  list5.insertFront(new Integer(test5[i]));
}
```

Comment: I felt, this `squish()` solution is less readable.